# SQLite, return data as an array

Tags: java, android, arrays, sqlite

I have an SQLite Database in my android application with the following structure:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  String CREATE_LISTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LISTS +
                              "("+
                              _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , " +
                              NOTE + " TEXT" +
                              ")";
  db.execSQL(CREATE_LISTS_TABLE);
}
```

And this works, in that I can insert data into it without a problem. However I need to store the notes inside an array. I currently have the following query:

```
public List<String> getAllNotes() {
  List<String> notes = new ArrayList<>();

  String GET_ALL_NOTES = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LISTS;

  SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
  if(db!=null)
  {
     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(GET_ALL_NOTES, null);
     cursor.moveToFirst();
     while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
     {
       notes.add(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("notes"))));
       cursor.moveToNext();
     }
     cursor.close();
  }
  db.close();

  return notes;
}
```

However, this gives the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

I was wondering how to fix this, I have read the android developer stuff but I can't seem to get anything to work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `col -1` means there is no `"notes"` column in your `Cursor`. Sure it's not just `"note"`? Why not just use `NOTE`, that was used to create the table?

Comment: Yeah im dumb, however it seems to only display 0, not the string thats stored. Any ideas?

Comment: If you stored a `String` in that column, why are you using `getInt()` to retrieve the value? Use `getString()`.

Comment: I cant thank you enough mate, ive been stuck on this for hours and it was a dumb as that. Thanks allot mate.

Comment: its just plain text from what i imagine so all you need is `notes.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("NOTE"));`

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of "NOTE", and use it in:
`notes.add(String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(NOTE))));`

I think a best way to make the call should be something like this:

```
// Check the cursor
    if(cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            // Variables to be used
            String note;

            // Col position
            int colNote = cursor.getColumnIndex(NOTE);

            do {
                // Get the information
                note = cursor.getString(colNote);

                // Add the note
                notes.add(note);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // Close the cursor
        cursor.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are fetching only integer and string from database, instead of using ArrayList , you can try using HashMap. So you can get the value by just giving the key.  Below simple code will work for ArrayList too with minor changes..

Try this

```
  HashMap<Integer,String> notes = new HashMap<Integer,String>() ;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(GET_ALL_NOTES, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext())

        {
            int i = cursor.getInt(0);
            String s = cursor.getString(1);
            notes.put (i,s) ;
        }

        cursor.close();
```